Assigning LinkedHashMap to POJO class in Java
I'm using Jackson ObjectMapper to map value from JSON to List<MyPojo> with TypeReference, like this
1:
List<MyPojo> myList= objectMapper.readValue("...json value...", new TypeReference<List<MyPojo>>() {});

but I have a few questions.
I know that TypeReference is used to capture the generic type and retain it at runtime, otherwise we will lose that info because of type erasure. But then I got warning:
"Explicit type argument List can be replaced with <> "
so I tried this:
2:
List<MyPojo> myList= objectMapper.readValue("...json value...", new TypeReference<>() {});

Again, everything works fine, but I'm wondering if this is a valid warning because objectMapper actually needs to know which type to map to?
So I run both .readValue(...) methods in debugger to see what the return value is. The first method call returns ArrayList of MyPojo, which is expected indeed, but second one returns ArrayList of LinkedHashMap. This is also expected because Jackson will map into LinkedHashMap by default, but I don't understand how is possible to simple assign ArrayList of LinkedHashMap to List od MyPojo, since compiler will not allow me to do this manually without some kind of conversion?

It's a valid warning. Using <> means: "Hey, compiler? Can you just figure out what I wanted to write here? Only one obvious thing can work, so please just assume I wrote that". In other words, it is identical to writing it out longform - if the compiler can figure it out for you.
It can figure it out for you here: Because you are assigning it directly to a variable of type List<MyPojo>, the compiler knows only TypeReference<List<MyPojo>> can possibly work here.
Contrast to replacing List<MyPojo> list = EXPR; with System.out.println(EXPR); - now the compiler would not know, so if you use <>, all the compiler can do is to go with Object (because that is the least restrictive thing it can generate that still works. It works, because System.out.println(Object) exists). And now at runtime, the objectMapper uses reflection to check the stuff in the <> of that TypeReference anonymous inner class literal, finds Object, and therefore does not know how to convert {foo: bar} in the input by making a new MyPojo instance - nobody told it about MyPojo, so now it would fail.
In other words, you can omit the stuff in the <> (but not the <> itself) if from context the compiler can figure out what should be in the <>. Whether it can or not depends on how you use it. Assigning to fields/parameters - generally yes. Passing to methods - sometimes, depends on how many overloads exist. Passing to generalized stuff like System.out.println? Then no - you have to write it out explicitly.
If in one of those 'it must be written out' scenarios that warning still occurs, then that is a faulty warning.
Note that supertypetokens (Which is what that TypeReference thing is) is a bit of a weird hack. It's plausible that linters mess up here (such as the thing telling you that <List<MyPojo>> can just be replaced with <> - that's a linting tool, javac itself doesn't care how you do it).
It's just in this specific case the warning is fair, and what you've done is fine. But other cases exist where you would not be able to replace <List<MyPojo>> with <>.

Thank you for the explanation, so this means that phase of "resolving" <> to get correct type, happens before type erasure so TypeReference is able to capture the type?

Correct. It's entirely the compiler's doing. The point of STTs is for the compiler to put this info in the anonymous class that the form new SomeType() {} generates (the {} do that), so that at runtime this info can be extracted. Ordinarily generics just disappears - hence, the whole point is to encode compiler-known info that is normally stripped out, into the super type token.

You can create a collection type via:
constructCollectionType(List.class, MyPojo.class) // CollectionType<List<MyPojo>>

Now, you can create a generic utility function around this:
public <E> List<E> fromJsonToList(ObjectMapper om, String json, Class<E> clazz) {
    try {
        return om.readValue(json, om.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, clazz));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error reading JSON data", e);
    }
}

And then use it:
List<MyPojo> myList= fromJsonToList(objectMapper, "[{}, {}]", MyPojo.class);

